# Including fontawesome in Angular with grunt

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, font-awesome

I read a lot about this issue but still did not find the solution.

I have an Angular application set up with Yeoman's generator whitout Sass. I tried to include fontawesome, so I used `bower install components-font-awesome --save`.

The problem is that when I `grunt build`my app, I have an error because fonts are not found in my dist folder :

```
GET http://myapp.com/bower_components/components-font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.0.3 404 (Not Found)
```

So I tried to add this to Grunt copy task in order to copy the fonts to the right directory:

```
{
     expand: true,
     cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components/components-font-awesome/fonts/',
     src: ['**'],
     dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/bower_components/components-font-awesome/fonts/'
}
```

But I am still getting the same error...

**EDIT**

Fonts seem to be available at `http://myapp.com`**/dist/**`bower_components/components-font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.0.3`

But not at the URI throwing the error (without /dist) ...

Comment: The `?v=4.0.3`, the query params, do not matter. Delete your `dist` directory. Run grunt. Check what files are changed by grunt. Make sure you serve your `dist` directory and not `src` or something else.

Comment: I can see the fonts files under `dist/bower_components/components-font-awesome/fonts/` such as FontAwesome.otf, fontawesome-webfont.woff etc.

Comment: Are you using the grunt task `cssmin` in your `grunt build` ? If so, try to comment the `root` option and try to redeploy. This option had caused me an issue with Bootstrap without Sass.

Comment: Yes I am using it, I just tried to comment `//root: '<%= yeoman.app %>'` but still the same error after grunt build

Comment: Without your grunt copy task, does grunt copies them to dist?

Comment: No without the copy task, nothing is copied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found to include icons in my Angular's application was to include glyphicons instead of fontawesome. The same problem is happening when grunt building my app with glyphicon, but the following copy task worked for me:

```
// Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
        copy: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    dot: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                    src: [
                        '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                        '.htaccess',
                        '*.html',
                        'views/{,*/}*.html',
                        'bower_components/**/*',
                        'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
                        'fonts/*'
                    ]
                }, {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/images',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
                    src: ['generated/*']
                }]
            },
            styles: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
                dest: '.tmp/styles/',
                src: '{,*/}*.css'
            }
        },
```